# checking if object id is in an array of object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a check to see if a logged-in user's id `req.user.id.` is in an array of followers of the user being checked in `req.params.id`, bit for some reason it doesn't work.

```
router.get('/api/:id/isfollowing', auth, async (req, res) => {

    if (req.params.id==req.user._id) {
        return res.status(200).send({ "isfollowing": "Myself" })
    }

    try {
        const followers = await Follow.find({
            user: req.params.id
        })

        let followersArr = followers.map(follower=>{
            return follower.followedBy
        })

        const yes = followersArr.includes(req.user._id)
        // const yes = followersArr.filter((objId) => objId==req.user._id)

        console.log(yes, followersArr, req.user._id)

        if (yes===false) {
            return res.status(200).send({ "isfollowing": false })
        }

        return res.status(200).send({ "isfollowing": true })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

for some reason the check doesn't work and even when using the filter, it still returns nothing. But when I `console.log` the values, it is right there.

```
[] [ 5fa4f0af4a7bf5471c41e225, 5f9dc1777a695570e878424d ] 5f9dc1777a695570e878424d
```

EDIT
schemas below

User schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        trim: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Passwoed cannot contain "password"')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

follow schema

```
const followSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // the logged in user who will be trying to follow someone will be added to "followedBy"
    // the user who is getting followed will be added to "user"
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    followedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Showcase'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

I gave follow its own schema so I can record other info like time and other info whenever a user follows another.

Comment: Can you provide your schema and an examplo for your collection? Thanks

Comment: @J.F. I just updated the post and added my model schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understand well you only need a simple query.

Since you only want to know if the `id` is into an array, you can check that directly with mongo. You don't need load every document into memory and use `JS` functions like `filter` or something similar.

You only need a query similar to this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "user": ObjectId("user_id"),
  "followedBy": ObjectId("follower_id")
})
```

This will return a document that match both values.

Check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OoRliHZsPPw) it works and tell me if is the behaviour and output you expect.

Also I will code a `mongoose` query and I'll update the answer.

You can use also this query in `mongoose` to get how many documents find the query:

```js
var find = await model.find({"user":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id),"followedBy":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(follower_id)}).countDocuments()
```

Comment: You are welcome! I have added some `mongoose` code in case it cuold help.

Answer (score 1):

Includes cannot be used in this case since you are trying to find ObjectId in an array.

To find if req.user._id is present in followersArr, use Array.some() function as below

```
const yes = followersArr.some(followerId=>{followerId.equals(req.user._id)})
```

The some call will iterate over the followersArr array, calling equals on each one to see if it matches req.user._id and stop as soon as it finds a match. If it finds a match it returns true, otherwise false.

You can't use something simpler like indexOf because you want to compare the ObjectIDs by value, not by reference.

Comment: bro, it still doesn't work for some reason even when I console.log the values and it's supposed to return true